# Acer laptop with Intel core i5-6200U Intel HD Graphics 520, can't resume from suspend

Tags: suspend, intel-graphics, acer

I'm running 17.04 on an Acer laptop with Intel core i5-6200U and Intel® HD Graphics 520, 8 GB RAM. after suspend I can't wake up the system, I have to force shut down using the power button.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Intel proprietary CPU driver solved the problem...

- go to **System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**
- click **Do not use the device >**
- click  <kbd>apply changes</kbd>
- restart the system